# Ogre3D Fog with overlays

Tags: ogre

I'm building a game with Ogre3d, I've got fog working properly with:
`scenemanager->setFog(Ogre::FOG_LINEAR, Ogre::ColourValue( 0.23f, 0.725f, 1.0f ), 0, 18, 20 );`

However I'm currently implementing a GUI system (libRocket) which is rendered on top of everything else, and this removes the fog, does anyone know how to fix this? (I'm using the default libRocket rendering system for ogre as included in the samples, but this problem also appears when using a semi-transparent overlay).

Comment: This *sounds* like 2 separate problems. I'll risk it: firstly you'll explicitly have to turn off fog for all the UI geometry (if it's 2D or has it's own perception of depth it shouldn't be influenced by anyting depth-based in the scene anyway). Secondly the additive geometry might behave a little strange because the fog color should be black (i.e fade-to-black instead to-fog-color since we're adding/subtracing)? Just a generic hunch :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Mogr3D, but I have built my own  UI rendering system. Probably libRocket does the same,

Try to do some tests by using the Overlay objects, if I'm correct they do not remove the fog from the SceneManager.

Does libRocket use .material files or vertex scripts that might remove the fog there?

Have you tried adding the fog AFTER adding the UI stuff ?